# Last activity date

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed

It would be useful if the API allowed you to return items based on their last activity date. Let's take a question for example.

/questions/fromlastactivitydate=XYZ&tolastactivitydate=XYZ

All questions having been created, edited, commented on or answered on as their last activity during the requested period would be returned.

There is already a last-activity field returned in the API, so I assume it would be a trivial concept to implement. It would be great if that could also be applied to Users as well.

The returned values should only include the activities that took place during that period of time, for example, only comments and answers that have been made during the requested period.

A possibly more complex, but related, query would be to provide an activity period, which doesn't have to be the last activity date of a question, and the returned values would be all questions which had activity during said period and including only answers/comments that were made during that period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that supports a `sort` of activity can do this already.

`?sort=activity&min={start-date}&max={end-date}`

Where `start-date` and `end-date` are unix timestamps.

---

**Update**

`/questions` and `/questions/unanswered` now honor `min`, `max`, and `order`.

```
sort     | min and max limit
--------------------------------
active   | last_activity_date
newest   | creation_date
featured | bounty_closes_date*
hot      | last_activity_date
week     | last_activity_date
month    | last_activity_date
votes    | score
```

`todate` and `fromdate`, as always, limit `creation_date`.

<sub>*bounty_closes_date is always in the future, as featured only returns those questions whose bounties haven't passed yet.</sub>

Comment: Of course, `/questions` doesn't haven an activity sort so you can't do it in that case... only creation date.

Comment: @ColinD - /questions has an `active` sort.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't support `min` and `max` so you can't do this.

Comment: @ColinD - well, it should.  Makes this a [bug].  Looking into it.

Comment: Just curious: none of the other sorts for `/questions` (including `votes` and `newest`) seem to support `min` or `max` or `order`, so I'd assumed it was an intentional restriction for all of them due to the large set of data involved. Are any of those supposed to have them too?

Comment: @ColinD - `/questions` and `/questions/unanswered` are going to have some restrictions when the dust settles due to data size.  Stay tuned for exactly what those restrictions turn out to be.